# How can I load an Image to Image() from a valid path or URL from Bundle in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a PNG file in my Bundle.main and I want use that URL or path to feed my Image in SwiftUI, right now I am using this down code, but I like to use just SwiftUI not UIKit mixed

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)!)
```

Do we have some initializing way for Image that accept path or url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to init from a filepath you could create an extension on Image that handles the boilerplate code for you. But you need to handle the case if the UIImage doesn't exist as the `Image(uiImage:)` expects a non-optional UIImage as a parameter.

Something like this should work:

```
extension Image {
    init(contentsOfFile: String) {
        // You could force unwrap here if you are 100% sure the image exists
        // but it is better to handle it gracefully
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: contentsOfFile) {
            self.init(uiImage: image)
        } else {
            // You need to handle the option if the image doesn't exist at the file path
            // let's just initialize with a SF Symbol as that will exist
            // you could pass a default name or otherwise if you like
            self.init(systemName: "xmark.octagon")
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
Image(contentsOfFile: "path/to/image/here")
```

Or you could use the property of `UIImage` to load from the bundle

```
extension Image {
    init(uiImageNamed: String) {
        if let image = UIImage(named: uiImageNamed, in: .main, compatibleWith: nil) {
            self.init(uiImage: image)
        } else {
            // You need to handle the option if the image doesn't exist at the file path
            self.init(systemName: "xmark.octagon")
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
Image(uiImageNamed: "ImageName")
```

Comment: I have a kind of your extension as form of function which do the same thing, I was very interested to bundle, that you maintained before you edited your answer, I tried this code but it does not worked, what I am doing wrong here? **Image("myImageName", bundle: Bundle(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myImageName", withExtension: "png")!))**

Comment: The code I removed doesn't work, that is why I removed it. `Image` appears to only look in asset catalogs,  where as `UIImage` looks in the bundle as well as the asset catalogs. So you cannot initialise the way you are trying there. Also what you are doing seems like a roundabout way to write `Bundle.main`

Comment: I noticed as well what you just said, do you think this is a bug that it goes asset catalog for searching? and not looking to given Bundle?

Comment: because apple says: Parameters:
name: the name of the image resource to lookup, as well as the
 localization key with which to label the image.
 bundle: the bundle to search for the image resource and localization
 content. If `nil`, uses the main `Bundle`. Defaults to `nil`.

Comment: It could be a bug, or it could be that Apple is expecting that all images should be contained in an asset catalog.

Comment: But I am sure it is a bug because of 2 reason, **first** for asset catalog we have this: Image("nameOfImage") and **second** who use Bundle for addressing a file from asset catalog? for asset catalog we just use the name of file, and since apple used Bundle property as initializing Image, it means for sure not asset catalog, are you agree with me because of 2 reasons?

Comment: You can have multiple bundles in your app (and they could contain asset catalogs) so you need to be able to have the option to tell which bundle it is. If you think it is a bug file a Feedback with Apple.

Comment: I never done it before, is it paid? or just feedback.

Comment: This helped me a lot! I've had a non-fatal console warning when compiling my app for a few months (nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost).  I narrowed the root down to an image I created and am using in my Assets catalog. When I implemented your extension, it resolved my error.  Thank you